# PHP - Add text to box without reload page

Tags: php, text, addition, reload

I want to add text without reloading the page.

Here I have 2 TField (each with button POS and NEG) and 2 TArea (1 TArea POS and 1 TArea NEG).
when i input some text in first TField and then press POS button, the text added to TArea POS, and vice versa, if there is input in second TField then i hit POS, then my input append to TArea POST too.

In pure php with using FORM I could do it. but here I want page without reloading.

```
<div id="retrain" >
<input type="text" id="tweet" name="tweet" title="Teks retrain"  />
<input type="submit" id="pos" name="pos" value="POS"/>
<input type="submit" id="neg" name="neg" value="NEG"/>
</div>
<div id="retrain" >
<input type="text" id="tweet" name="tweet" title="Teks retrain"  />
<input type="submit" id="pos" name="pos" value="POS"/>
<input type="submit" id="neg" name="neg" value="NEG"/>
</div>

<div id="box" >
<textarea style="width:420px" name="posbox" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
<textarea style="width:420px" name="negbox" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
</div>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['pos'])) {

  }
  if (isset($_POST['neg'])) {

  }
  ?>
```

Can you help my case?
Thanks for the help.

**note** : here i using same ID for all my input.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do asynchronous requests with php. It is server compiled, not like javascript that is compiled by the browser..

learn how the internet works!

Comment: why can't? i just to need append text to box without using pure php. say it can be work using ajax or jq.

Answer (score 0):

You can change fields in html with Javascript. The problem of your code is that your buttons are "submit" and thus a form has to be submitted (the page reloaded, etc). With these small changes you can get what you want:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
      function changeField()
      {
          document.form1.tweet.value=document.form0.tweet.value;
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <form name='form0' id='form0'>
        <div id="retrain" >
        <input type="text" id="tweet" name="tweet" title="Teks retrain"  />
        <input type="submit" id="pos" name="pos" value="POS"/>
        <input type="submit" id="neg" name="neg" value="NEG"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form name='form1' id='form1'>
        <div id="retrain" >
        <input type="text" id="tweet" name="tweet" title="Teks retrain"  />
        <input type="submit" id="pos" name="pos" value="POS"/>
        <button type="button" id="neg" name="neg" value="NEG" onclick="changeField();">NEG</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

Logically, the only button including the new functionality is "neg" in form1: when it is clicked, the text in the "tweet" textbox above is written into the one below.